# Can we work Telerik 2010 versions on Visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

Can we work with RadControls Telerik versions of 2009-2010 on .NET 4.0.
Is this possible to install over.

Comment: It is high time you accept an answer. Otherwise no one will upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent website I have worked on was developed using asp.net 3.5 and some older 2010 telerik controls.

When we purchased VS 2010, I went ahead and upgraded the site to .net 4.0 and the tools still functioned just fine.

Comment: thanks! right now iam using Visula studio  2010 and tried to add tool telerik  onto it.  but some kind of error it show, and using the visual studio 2010 ultimate edition 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik installation (any versions in the recent past) usually gives you different DLLs for each version of .net(2.0,3.5,4.0). All you need to do is use the right one based on the .net framework version your application is running.